# How to change the height of UIScrollView using Interfacebuilder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

How to change the Height of a `UIScrollVIew` using only `InterfaceBuilder` ?

Changing the height field in `Show the Size inspector` doesn't work

I am using xCode 4.3.1

Comment: there is content size (the size of your virtual "table") and also the view size. What do you miss?

Comment: Where is it ? is it in the `Show the Size inspector` tab ?

Comment: Is it the 683 value you are talking about. I have changed it and nothing hapence. + This is what i was saying in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to change the height of the scrollView, you need to adjust its frame. You can do this as simply as saying

```
theScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
```

You obviously need to fill in the values of x, y, width, and height. If you are looking to do it in Interface Builder, open the nib that contains your scroll view. In the Utilities section (the right-most section), click the Size Inspector (the ruler icon). Select your scroll view, and under the "View" section, you can adjust the height.

If you're looking for a way to adjust the height at run time through interface builder, there is no way. Interface Builder allows you to adjust what your view looks like when it is unloaded from its corresponding nib file. Once that file is unloaded, you would need to make changes to its frame programmatically.

Comment: I have increased the Height to 900, but it still shows like 480 of the scrollview (Using IB)

Comment: If you have a view that is 900 points tall, how would you expect to see the whole thing on a device that is 480 points tall? If you have 900 points of content and you want the user to scroll down to see that stuff beyond y = 480, you set the contentSize of the scrollView, not the frame of the scroll view.